# Finding entries where at least 2 rows have a value of x

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stumbled across a problem which I have been stuck on for some time.

I have a judging table (exp_judging) which holds multiple rows of the same rel_id with different judge_id's. Normally there is at least 3 rows with the same rel_id.

I need to return entry_id where there are at least 2 rows with a '1' in the 'stage_1' column, with each row having the same rel_id, stage_2 IS NULL and member_group is equal to 5.

The following query is the closet I feel I have got, but I imagine its still a mile off.

```
SELECT sub.entry_id
FROM exp_judging AS jud
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
WHERE jud.stage_2 IS NULL
AND (jud.stage_1=1) >= 2
AND sub.member_group = 5
GROUP BY jud.rel_id
LIMIT 1
```

If anyone could shed some light on how I can achieve this I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

SQL FIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d7e2/1

Comment: Post your table, data and query on sqlfiddle.com then advise.

Comment: @Tarik I have created a sqlfiddle and added the link to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sub.entry_id
FROM exp_judging AS jud
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
WHERE jud.stage_2 IS NULL
AND jud.stage_1 = 1 
AND sub.member_group = 5
GROUP BY jud.rel_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```